# Create model class for list of objects within an object

Tags: flutter, dart

Don't ask me why the response is like this, it just is:

```
{
  "items": {
    "01": {
        "title": "One"
    },
    "02": {
        "title": "Two"
    },
    "03": {
        "title": "Three"
    },
    "04": {
        "title": "Four"
    }
  }
}
```

`"items"` really should be an array here instead of an object, but it isn't, and I can't change it.

So how do I create a model class for this such that the items are treated as being part of an array instead, like:

```
[{"title": "One"},{"title": "Two"},{"title": "Three"},{"title": "Four"}]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your response call `dataMap`, you can convert it to list of map like this:

```
var _list = (dataMap["items"] as Map<String, Map<String, String>>)
    .values
    .map((e) => e)
    .toList();
```

now if you print `_list`, result would be:

```
[{title: One}, {title: Two}, {title: Three}, {title: Four}]
```

now you can convert it to a List of class model like this:

```
var result = _list.map((e) => ItemModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
```

and this is the class:

```
class ItemModel {
  final String title;

  ItemModel({required this.title});

  static ItemModel fromJson(Map<String, String> map) {
    return ItemModel(title: map["title"] ?? '');
  }
}
```

now if you print the `result`, it show you this:

```
[Instance of 'ItemModel', Instance of 'ItemModel', Instance of 'ItemModel', Instance of 'ItemModel']
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a better way to create a model class for the items, instead of making one for each, i.e. a class for 01, a class for 02, a class for 03, etc.?

Comment: what do you mean by `a class for 01`?

Comment: @user5721807 check out my update, is that what you want?

Comment: What if each item object had an int key/value aswell, like `"order": 0`, `"order": 1`, etc?

Comment: Can you show me the final class that you want?! @user5721807